# How to center an option in a select menu using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like for all the options in a select menu to be centered, however I can't find a way of doing it.

After a quick google I couldn't find any real solutions, however most of the entries are quite old, so I'm wondering if there have been any improvements made to css to make this possible.

The closest I've found is to use text indentation, which may well work for the options that are the same length, but for any options of varying lengths it of course looks off.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code to receive solution for your problem.

Comment: You could always find the longest option within the list and then pad all of the other options with spaces to match the length.

Comment: use a custom select element eg. using jQuery UI, and you will be able to style the items as you see fit.

Comment: I'm with @Banana. It's worth noting that `<select>` menus can look very different on certain devices. Phones may switch you to a fullscreen menu of their options. Tablets might expand them in both directions and with extra padding. It's true that `<select>` is ugly and near-impossible to style correctly, just keep in mind that you have to weigh the benefits of usability against appearance.

Comment: Yes, surely it should be easier than this, but I am resigning myself to the fact that I'm going to have to use something other than plain CSS

Comment: @Codedstuff while the `<select>` is an html element, the menu it drops down is not; it is rendered by the OS. the drop down list of the same select box will be rendered differently per operating system. your only option is to do it crudely with indentation or create a custom select box.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using `ul` and `li` instead of a traditional `select` and `option`.

Bootstrap has a component that lets you do this: [Single button dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single).

You can use their component and add a style similar to this:

```
ul.btn-dropdown li {
  text-align: center;
}
```

You can get a result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTML/CSS doesn't provide for formatting Option elements within Select lists - only for formatting the whole Select list.

You could try padding with spaces but, realistically, I'd concentrate on more important issues and let Select lists be Select lists.

(JQuery may have something to offer, but I do straight Javascript so am not familiar enough to know).

Tony Duffill